# How do I create an OData v2 endpoint in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm attempting to implement an OData endpoint using ASP.NET Web API.  I installed the *Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 for OData 1-3* package from nuget and I think what I have running is an OData v3 endpoint.

$metadata:

```
<edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:DataServiceVersion="3.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0">
```

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Builder;

public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<MyModel>("MyModels");
        config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
    }
}
```

I just found out my intended client app can only support OData v2.  Is there a way to configure Web API to speak in OData v2 instead of or in addition to OData v3?

Answer (score 1):

Set the version and max version of your service on the model builder:

```
var odataVersion2 = new Version(2, 0);
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.DataServiceVersion = odataVersion2;
builder.MaxDataServiceVersion = odataVersion2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the version of DataService (OData Version), Edm (CSDL Version) and Edmx:

```
var version = Microsoft.Data.Edm.Csdl.CsdlConstants.EdmxVersion2;
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder
{
   // OData V2.0
   DataServiceVersion = version,
   MaxDataServiceVersion = version
};
// Generate Model
var edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();
// CSDL Version 2.0
edmModel.SetEdmVersion(version);
// Set Edmx Version
edmModel.SetEdmxVersion(version);
```